# fetching customers who re-subscribed on their own

Tags: mysql, join

I have a payments table I reproduced on the following sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d31c9

I'm trying to extract the following data :

- fetch the customers who RE-subscribed on their own (that means "type" equals "SUBSCRIPTION" and "advisor_create" equals 0) in 2015. To be considered as a RE-subscriber, the customer should have at least one previous payment with type "SUBSCRIPTION" (year and advisor_create are not important for this previous payment)
- I'll have more data to extract once this base query is working, like knowing if these customers re-subscribed for a different offer or the same one, if their new subscription is cheaper or more expensive than the previous one.

In the sqlfiddle example data I provided, this query should return the customers #2 (due to payment id #4) and #5 (due to payment id #8).

Right now, I wrote the following query :

```
SELECT p.id, p.customer_id, p.date, p.type, p.offer, p.value
FROM payments p
WHERE p.type = "SUBSCRIPTION"
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015
AND advisor_create = 0
```

But I have no idea how to self join this query with the payment table to check if subscriptions occured in the past for these customers.
Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE #1 :**

According to the answer below, I tried to work with the second part of my problem and tried the following query :

```
SELECT p.customer_id, P.offer, p.value, previous_payments.offer AS previous_offer, previous_payments.value AS previous_value
FROM payments p 
JOIN payments previous_payments ON ( 
    previous_payments.customer_id = p.customer_id 
    AND previous_payments.date < p.date 
    AND previous_payments.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION' 
) 
WHERE p.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION' 
AND p.advisor_create = 0 
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015
GROUP BY p.customer_id
```

The data for customer #5 are wrong, previous_offer and previous value should equals 21 and 14, as this is the **latest** previous subscription for this customer. How can I make the join runs on the latest previous subscription ?

**UPDATE #2**

According to my comment pointing out an error in the final result set, I fixed your latest query (the one with temporary join table, see your EDIT 2 part) like this :

```
SELECT p.customer_id, p.offer, p.value, previous_payments.offer AS previous_offer, previous_payments.value AS previous_value
FROM payments p
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM payments
    JOIN ( select customer_id, max(date) as date from payments p1
        where date < ( select max(date) from payments p2 where p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id and p2.advisor_create = 0 )
    group by customer_id ) p2 USING (customer_id, date)
    WHERE type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
) previous_payments ON previous_payments.customer_id = p.customer_id AND previous_payments.date < p.date
WHERE p.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
AND p.advisor_create = 0
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015;
```

Is that correct ? 
Just added `and p2.advisor_create = 0` in the sub-sub-sub-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to self join this query with the payment table

Here is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT p.customer_id
FROM payments p
JOIN payments previous_payments ON (
    previous_payments.customer_id = p.customer_id 
    AND previous_payments.date < p.date 
    AND previous_payments.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
)
WHERE p.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
AND p.advisor_create = 0
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015
GROUP BY p.customer_id;
```

There are plenty other options though.

**EDIT**

Ok so apparently this only answers half your problem. The reason you are not getting the right previous payments with the above query is because of the `GROUP BY`. So we need to remove it. Let's decompose the problem.

You need to know the previous payment. That is the **second to last** payment.

Here is how to get the date of the last payment of a given customer:

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM payments WHERE customer_id = X;
```

Here is how to get the date of the second to last payment of a given customer:

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM payments p1
WHERE p1.date < ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM payments p2 WHERE p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id )
AND p1.customer_id = X
```

Now we can add this as a where clause to the original query in a correlated subquery, to only keep the last payment, and therefore remove the group by.

```
SELECT p.customer_id, p.offer, p.value, previous_payments.offer AS previous_offer, previous_payments.value AS previous_value
FROM payments p
JOIN payments previous_payments ON (
    previous_payments.customer_id = p.customer_id 
    AND previous_payments.date < p.date 
    AND previous_payments.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
)
WHERE p.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
AND p.advisor_create = 0
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015
AND previous_payments.date = (
    SELECT MAX(date) FROM payments p1
    WHERE date < ( SELECT MAX(date) FROM payments p2 WHERE p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id )
    AND p1.customer_id = p.customer_id
);
```

Returns:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+
| customer_id | offer | value | previous_offer | previous_value |
+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+
|           2 |    23 | 11.00 |             21 |          12.00 |
|           5 |    21 | 15.00 |             21 |          14.00 |
+-------------+-------+-------+----------------+----------------+
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is another way to write the same query, without the correlated subquery, but using a temporary join table instead (so it might be faster):

```
SELECT p.customer_id, p.offer, p.value, previous_payments.offer AS previous_offer, previous_payments.value AS previous_value
FROM payments p
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM payments
    JOIN ( select customer_id, max(date) as date from payments p1
        where date < ( select max(date) from payments p2 where p1.customer_id = p2.customer_id )
    group by customer_id ) p2 USING (customer_id, date)
    WHERE type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
) previous_payments ON previous_payments.customer_id = p.customer_id AND previous_payments.date < p.date
WHERE p.type = 'SUBSCRIPTION'
AND p.advisor_create = 0
AND YEAR(p.date) = 2015;
```

Comment: If I want to make sure the payment considered as a RE-subscription is in 2015, I should just add `WHERE YEAR(p.date) = 2015` in the main query ?

Comment: @VaN Yes sorry, I forgot about that. I edited my answer.

Comment: ok, thank you, your query works ok, except for 1 thing, I need the join on previous payments to be made on latest previous subscription. I updated original post so you can see where the probleme is.

Comment: @VaN I see. Well this complicates things a bit. I have edited my answer with a solution, but there might be other ways.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth explanation, I totally understand the logic behind your updated queries. But both updated queries only return customer #5. customer #2 is skipped from the results. I can't understand why.

Comment: After investigation, I can tell the problem is probably in the JOIN subquery. If I run this query alone, which is supposed to return the latest previous subscription before their latest self-subscription, it returns 3 customers, #2, #4 and #5. But customer #2 row is wrong, because payment #11 is not a subscription made on his own (advisor_create = 1 for this row). The row for customer #2 in this subquery should be payment #2, not payment #4. Do you follow my reasoning here ? I think I found how to correct that, see updated original post and confirm my changes please : )

Comment: @VaN What? With the data you have given, both queries return customers #2 and #5. See [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d31c9/31/0). There is no payment #11 in your data set.

Comment: mhh sorry, I probably added this row after creating the sqlfiddle. You can add payment #11 with this : `INSERT INTO payments (id, customer_id, date, type, offer, value, advisor_create) VALUES (11, 2, '2015-08-26', 'SUBSCRIPTION', 23, '15.00', 1);` Can you confirm the correction I made to your query correctly handle this case ?

Comment: @VaN With your new data, customer #2 is not returned because his last re-subscription has not been made by him. I understood this is what you wanted. Now if you want "customers that re-subscribed on their own *at least once*, but not necessarily in the last time" then yes your modification looks right.

Comment: You're totally right, I gave confusing requirements. Now I realize what I need is "customers that re-subscribed on their own at least once, but not necessarily in the last time". So i'll stick with my modification. When I first ran your query in real-data environnment, I called the whole office to see the query, you're kind a a hero today here : ) This query is astonishingly complex yet runs in 8 seconds on a 350k+ rows table. I'm now tweaking it to get a lot of stats from re-subs. Thank you, you're a SQL genius to me. +1 for your post + accepted answer, probably not worth the time spent :p